# How to insert rows using values from mulitple columns in the same table where there are over 100 columns? Possible use LOOP?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

enter code here

Lets say i have the following table:

```
ID Name    ID2 ID3 ID4 ID100
1   Smith   2   3   4   100
20  Joe     10  20  30  200
30  Jane    40  50  60  300
```

How can i write a statement that goes thru columns ID2 - ID100 one at a time and take the values from the column and the Name column and adds a new row to the table?

To look like so:

```
ID Name    ID2 ID3 ID4 ID100
1   Smith   2   3   4   100
2   Smith               
3   Smith               
4   Smith               
100 Smith
```

Ive done this, but done want to write 100 select lines.

```
INSERT INTO mytable
(ID, Name)
SELECT ID2, Name FROM mytable WHERE Name = 'Smith'
UNION ALL
SELECT ID3, Name FROM mytable WHERE Name = 'Smith'
UNION ALL
SELECT ID4, Name FROM mytable WHERE Name = 'Smith';
```

Comment: Why have you designed this mess? Create another table which references this table via foreign-key and contains those values.

Comment: It looks very much like those 100 columns should instead be rows in a child table with a FK to the parent.  Maybe that observation's not helpful at this point, but it might be for your next DB design.

Comment: Write the lines using formulas in Excel.  Then copy them into your SQL interface.

Comment: is this sql server or mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Your database violates First Normal Form by creating repeating groups.  An RDBMS is not designed to handle this design cleanly.  This is precisely why you don't want to create repeating groups.  Any solution other than redesign will be ugly and slow.

The answer, if redesign isn't an option, is to do the painful part once and then not need do it again.

Create the following view:

```
CREATE VIEW MyUglyTable_Unpivot (ID, Name, Field_ID, Field_Value) AS
SELECT ID, Name, 'ID2',   ID2   FROM MyTable WHERE ID2   IS NOT NULL UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Name, 'ID3',   ID3   FROM MyTable WHERE ID3   IS NOT NULL UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Name, 'ID4',   ID4   FROM MyTable WHERE ID4   IS NOT NULL UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Name, 'ID5',   ID5   FROM MyTable WHERE ID5   IS NOT NULL UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Name, 'ID6',   ID6   FROM MyTable WHERE ID6   IS NOT NULL UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Name, 'ID7',   ID7   FROM MyTable WHERE ID7   IS NOT NULL UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Name, 'ID8',   ID8   FROM MyTable WHERE ID8   IS NOT NULL UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Name, 'ID9',   ID9   FROM MyTable WHERE ID9   IS NOT NULL UNION ALL
...
SELECT ID, Name, 'ID99',  ID99  FROM MyTable WHERE ID99  IS NOT NULL UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Name, 'ID100', ID100 FROM MyTable WHERE ID100 IS NOT NULL
```

Obviously, you can pick more sensible names for the view and the fields.  You can leave out the `WHERE XXXX IS NOT NULL` if the underlying table has `NOT NULL` constraints on those fields, but in my experience they don't.  You could also leave it out if you know you really need explicit `NULL` values, but that's generally considered poor design.  `NULL` is too ambiguous.

The view will be slow as hell, but it will let you do operations like this more easily.  If you're able to redesign your system to not use repeating groups, I strongly encourage you to do so.

Now you can do this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (ID, Name)
SELECT Field_Value, Name FROM MyUglyTable_Unpivot
WHERE Name = 'Smith'
```

Although, I'm thinking you need to have `Field_ID` in `MyTable` somewhere to make sense of it all.

Answer (score -1):

its possible if you use foreign key concept otherwise use excel to write those select